# Finding (x,y) coordinates where z passes a test in numpy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I have a 16x16x4 array in Numpy.

Dimension 1: Horizontal position [0,15]

Dimension 2: Vertical position [0,15]

Dimension 3: An RGB value 0-255 [0,3]

Replace 16x16 with 2048x1285 and:

```
for x in range(0,15):
    for y in range(0,15):
```

Doesn't cut it (upwards of 7 minutes to do this and a flood fill at each interesting point). Iterating over a PIL image is plenty fast, but a numpy array drags (i.e. 7+ minutes).

```
numpy.where(bitmap == [red, green, blue, alpha])
```

doesn't seem like it's what I'm looking for. What's a reasonably fast way to go about this?

Edit:

```
bitmap == [red, green, blue, alpha]
```

is actually almost useful. How do I go from a 16x16x4 array to a 16x16x1 array where array[x,y] is 1 if z = [True,True,True,True] and 0 otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by `a flood fill at each interesting point`? Is it possible that the processing you're doing at each point that meets the criteria is taking more time than the search for those points?

Comment: When bitmap = Image.open("image.jpeg").load()

Comment: When bitmap = Image.open("image.jpeg").load(), the same loop completes in 2-3 seconds.

When bitmap = numpy.asarray(Image.open("image.jpeg")), that loop takes 7.5 minutes. (I wouldn't mind just working off the PIL image, but it will eventually be coming out of skimage.color.colorconv, which operates on NumPy arrays). (Sorry, last comment submitted on the enter key and was not editable when I was done composing...)

Comment: I think you may want to post a bit more of the loop content? Python loops are slow, but since thats mostly python and not numpy the same code in PIL should not be faster unless numpy does something differently.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your speeds -- even a brute-force iteration on my now-ancient notebook is about 14 times faster -- and I'm not sure `where` works the way you think it does, so I suspect that most of your time is spent elsewhere (say in your fill).  Anyway:

> How do I go from a 16x16x4 array to a 16x16x1 array where array[x,y]
>   is 1 if z = [True,True,True,True] and 0 otherwise?

I would:

```
In [169]: m = numpy.random.randint(0, 16, size=(2048, 1285, 4))

In [170]: b = [4,5,6,7]

In [171]: matches = (m == b).all(axis=2)*1

In [172]: matches.shape
Out[172]: (2048, 1285)
```

and it's pretty fast:

```
In [173]: timeit matches = (m == b).all(axis=2)*1
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating with `for` loops on a `ndarray` isn't very efficient, as you have noticed. If you want to find the indices of the entries satisfying your condition, you should indeed use

```
indices = np.where(bitmap == [R, G, B, A])
```

This will return a 3-element tuple giving the indices of the solution along the 1st, 2nd and third axis. As you're only interested in the first two dimensions, you can drop the third item. And if you want a series of indices like `(x,y)`, you just have to use something like

```
zip(*indices[:2])
```

A second possibility is to view your `(N,M,4)` standard integer `ndarray` into a `(N,M)` structured array with `dtype=[[('',int)]*4]` (don't bother for the field names, they'll be automatically expended to `'f0', 'f1', ...` :

```
alt_bitmap = bitmap.view([('',int)'*4).squeeze()
```

(The `squeeze` is introduced to collapse the `(N,M,1)` array into a `(N,M)` array)

You can then use the `np.where` function, but the values you're testing must be a `np.array` too:

```
indices = np.where(bitmap==np.array((R, G, B, A), dtype=bitmap.dtype))
```

This time, `indices` will only be a 2-tuple, and you can get the `(x,y)` couples with the `zip(*indices)` presented earlier.

Comment: I think there should be an `np.all(bitmap==..., -1)`, or both be viewed as a rec array. To force all being equal or an `any` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Well, with `a=np.arange(16*16*4).reshape(16,16,4)`, `np.where(a==[956,957,958,959])` gives you the tuple `indices=(array([14, 14, 14, 14]), array([15, 15, 15, 15]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))`, as expected...

Comment: Yes, but I mean: `a=np.arange(16*16*4).reshape(16,16,4); a[:,:,0] = 0; print np.where(a==[0,957,958,959])`

Comment: The code you posted gives me a list of every pixel with at least 1 duplicate per pixel. not all bitmap[x,y] == [255, 255, 255, 255] but that's what numpy.where reports...

Comment: Also a solution along the 3rd axis has no meaning, because (i.e.) 255 is never going to be equal to [255,255,255,255]. Is it possible checking for equality with a list means Numpy checks for any of those items?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I described is achieved by

```
zip(*numpy.where(numpy.logical_and.reduce(image == [255,255,255])))
```

Which was not clear according to any documentation, but there you have it. (Edit: lack of alpha channel is not significant.)

The test I'm interested in isn't actually equality to a point, but Euclidian distance to that point being within a threshold.

```
numpy.apply_along_axis(distance_from_white ...
```

where distance_from_white is a function returning Euclidian distance from white, works at 16x16 but takes minutes at 2048x1245. scipy.spatial.distance.pdist (or cdist?) might be the answer there, but I can't figure out how to make it compute distance against a single point instead of distance between all points in 2 arrays (this works at 16x16, but it's so much wasted computation I'm hesitant to even try it at actual size).

Comment: constructing `m` and `b` as in @DSM 's answer, the Euclideain distance against a point being less than a threshold is given by `numpy.sum(np.sqrt((m - b) ** 2), axis=2) < threshold`